# How do i query table A and B,fetch a column from B and add it to the result ? Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query two tables, Hostel and Room by joining them then fetch `Hostel.name` where my `Room.hostel_id == Hostel.id` so that my final query has Room data and a name from Hostel class, the `Hostel.name`.

Below are my classes
**Hostel**

```
class Hostel(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "hostel"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)    
    management = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False) 
    rooms = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    caretaker = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)  
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

**Room**

```
class Room(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "room"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rent = db.Column(db.Integer)
    deposit = db.Column(db.Integer)
    amenities = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    size= db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    hostel_id = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable = False)
```

I have the following lines of code that I've tried working with;

```
room_data = Room.query\
    .join(Hostel, Room.id==Hostel.id)\
    .add_columns(Hostel.name)\
    .filter(Room.hostel_id == Hostel.id)
```

and

```
room_data = Room.query.join(Hostel).filter(Room.hostel_id == Hostel.id).order_by(Room.id.desc()).all()
```

Help me fix this so that my query has all the details from the Room table and a new column that is from the hostel table that has the respective hostel name

Comment: I think your first query is the right way to go about it, but you just have a typo in the join which should be `join(Hostel, Room.hostel_id == Hostel.id)`

Comment: Thanks, @van, adding a relationship helped me fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, y'all. I simply added a relationship and used a backref to get the fields from the parent table

Added the following to my **room** table;

```
hostel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("hostel.id"), nullable=False)
hostel = db.relationship("Hostel", backref=db.backref("hostel"), lazy=True)
```